# CVE-2016-6662 + MySQL 5.5.52

Tags: linux, mysql

According to different Websites MySQL 5.5.52 [[1]](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=mysql) [[2]](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2016/q3/481) is affected by CVE-2016-6662.

At the [MySQL 5.5.52 Release Notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-52.html) i see that the security problem should got fixed in the 5.5.52 release:

> For mysqld_safe, the argument to --malloc-lib now must be one of the directories /usr/lib, /usr/lib64, /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu, or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. In addition, the --mysqld and --mysqld-version options can be used only on the command line and not in an option file. (Bug #24464380)

I am unsure if i am affected or not, the exact installed version on my server, which is running on CentOS 6, is `mysql-5.5.52-36.el6.art.x86_64` from the webtatic repo.

The paper on [legalhackers.com](http://legalhackers.com/advisories/MySQL-Exploit-Remote-Root-Code-Execution-Privesc-CVE-2016-6662.html) from Dawid Golunski, which had found that issue, does not list my mysql version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the [Oracle Critical Patch Update release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/security-advisory/cpuoct2016-2881722.html#AppendixMSQL) agree with the CVE descriptions, 5.5.52 is affected.

As to the legalhacker link, considering that he published that six days after 5.5.52 was released I'd guess that he never tested that version.